# Email notifier that supports Online accounts, notifications, Messaging Menu

Tags: notification, online-accounts, messaging-menu, email-client

Is there an email notifier application that:

- can be found in the Ubuntu repositories (not in a PPA),
- is integrated with the Online Accounts in Unity,
- shows notifications in message bubbles in the top right corner in Unity (dunno how it's called),
- is integrated with the Messaging Menu in Unity?

Unfortunately I didn't find any so far and Online Accounts support would be important for me.

Comment: How about [Unity-Mail](https://launchpad.net/unity-mail)? It integrates with messaging menu & show notification bubble. Online account support is comming soon(AFAIK).Screenshots: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qb0L6.png, http://i.stack.imgur.com/YcixM.png

Answer (score 0):

IF you really want UOA integration then you should try Evolution (& `evolution-indicator` plugin). Otherwise Unity-Mail has  most of the required features.

### [Unity Mail](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-mail) [image: Install unity-mail]

**Launchpad:** https://launchpad.net/unity-mail

With Unity Mail we can handle multiple gmail accounts. You will get an OSD notification whenever you receive a new mail showing the sender, and the subject of a mail.

[image]

In addition it adds a launcher icon to display the count of unread messages, integrates with the mail indicator to turn it blue, and displays a list of mails in the drop down menu there.

[image]

### Install it using:

`sudo apt-get install unity-mail`

[image: Install via the software center]

---

### [Evolution](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/evolution) [image: Install evolution]

- Has messaging menu support
- Show notification bubble
- Integrated with Ubuntu Online Accounts
- no ppa

[image: screenshot]

### Install it with following command:

`sudo apt-get install evolution evolution-indicator`

Comment: Thanks! I use Thunderbird, wouldn't like to switch to Evolution. :)

Comment: Thunderbird has its own messaging menu integration & also shows notification bubble. Its doesn't use online account which I think is good because online accounts has lots of bugs.

Comment: Unity mail does not work for me (Ubuntu 20).